# Time in W3C format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, timezone, w3c

How do i render time in W3C Format, including hours, minutes, seconds and timezone offset.

Example:

```
1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
```

**Update 1**

I have following declaration in config/locales/my_locale.yml:

```
time:
  formats:
    w3c: %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M
```

The only missing part is offset, like "+01:00". What is a interpolation symbol for it ?

I've found [this](http://amcubes.com/2007/12/12/formating-date-time-in-rails/) reference, which contains time zone **name**, interpolated with %Z.

But, where is **offset** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert time zone **offset** value, %z key (lowercase letter) should be used.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you should use %:z to include the + symbol. You also need to include the seconds.

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"
```

Update: Note that this is only possible with Ruby 1.9.3+, the %:z format token is not available in earlier versions!

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the answer but I just wanted to say that since this is not depended on the user locale but a standard defined by an organization it might be better to keep it outside of locale file such as en.yml

I personally add

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:w3c] = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:w3c] = "%Y-%m-%d"
```

at the bottom of `application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file `config/initializers/time_formats.rb` and put:

```
::Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  dashed_date:                     '%Y-%m-%d',               # 2021-03-30
  dashed_date_with_time:           '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p',       # 2021-03-30 08:16PM
  short_month_day_year:            '%b %d, %Y',              # Mar 30, 2021
  slashed_date_with_time_and_zone: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z',   # 03/30/2021 08:16:18 UTC
  time:                            '%-m/%e/%y %H:%M',        # 03/30/2021 18:16
  text_date:                       '%B %d, %Y',              # March 30, 2021
  twenty_four_hour_time:           '%H:%M:%S',               # 22:24:49
  twenty_four_hour_time_and_zone:  '%H:%M:%S %Z',            # 22:24:49 UTC
  utc_timezone:                    '%Z',                     # UTC
  w3c:                             '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z'
)
```

Then use `somting.updated_at.to_s(:w3c)`